# Is NSData/Data storage contiguous?

Tags: swift, nsdata

Are Data/NSData bytes guaranteed to be stored in contiguous memory?  Looking at the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data), I'm under the impression that one can access a contiguous representation of the bytes using `withUnsafeBytes()` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes()`.  However, it is possible that the bytes are copied from non-contiguous storage to a contiguous block when these methods are invoked.

I think it would be somewhat inefficient to copy the bytes when accessing them via those `withUnsafe...` methods, and the bytes are evidently stored contiguously when the `init(bytesNoCopy: ...)` initializer is used, so I tend to think that they are always stored contiguously, but haven't seen any docs stating so explicitly.

Comment: See for yourself: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Data.swift

Comment: Thank you, Alexander, for the source code link.  Looking at the code was a good educational experience and I found a statement, in `enumerateBytes()` comments, that storage is not guaranteed to be contiguous, which was then confirmed by @Rob.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `Data` is not guaranteed to be stored in contiguous memory. If you use `withUnsafeBytes` or `withUnsafeMutableBytes`, though, it will copy all the buffers to a single contiguous buffer.

If you do not want to incur that overhead, you can access the individual buffers using the [`regions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3139152-regions) property.

Comment: If `withUnsafeBytes` makes a contiguous copy, then why is it not safe to use the pointer passed to its closure outside of that closure? It seems to me that if any of the copies are to be recycled after the call, it should be the one that's not contiguous

Comment: Because that contiguous buffer could be released and reused after the closure is done. They only guarantee the integrity of that buffer until you return from that closure.

Comment: Why would the contiguous as opposed to the original be released? Especially since the probability of the function being called again in the future is much higher if it's been called once already.

Comment: First, it's a logistical issue: You're dealing with an unsafe pointer, not an object, so ARC semantics don't apply. How would you inform the OS when you're done with it and it could be released? We definitely don't want to go back to a `malloc`/`free` world. Second, it's reality. It's just how it works. They explicitly warn you not to use the buffer after you return from the API's closure.

Comment: Third, it's more memory efficient. There is a cost to keeping things in contiguous blocks. If it felt like it had to break it up in the first place, there might be situations where it's impractical to keep contiguous buffer around.

Answer (score 2):

The presence of `withUnsafeBytes` is a way of documenting that they reserve the right to not store the bytes contiguously, but can provide them that way on demand.

This might be because they imagine NSData would be ported to memory constrained environments and they don't want you to have system dependent code.